# Python Variable initialized outside function, assigned a value in function and reused outside the function

Tags: python, function, variables

Hi I am working with python doing a small keras project. I have a function which assigns a value to a string. However, I want to use that value outside of the function. Therefore, I initialized the value before the function, assigned a value to it, and used it afterwards, as follow.

Variable Initialized:

```
predictedLabelString = ''
```

Variable assigned value in function:

```
def predict_image_util(finalPredictedInv): 
    predictedLabelString = 'Crack'
```

Variable used outside function:

```
plt.title(predictedLabelString)
```

However, this returns nothing. What am I doing wrong please? Thanks

Comment: in the function write **global predictedLabelString** before you assign value to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `predict_image_util` function basically creates a local variable and so no change is found in the global variable with the same name.

Modify your function as follows:

```py
def predict_image_util(finalPredictedInv): 
    global predictedLabelString 
    predictedLabelString = 'Crack'
```

This would change the global value of the variable `predictedLabelString`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a global variable makes it difficult to debug, I would rather suggest using a function and return value in a local function context.

```py
def predict_image_util(finalPredictedInv): 
    predictedLabelString = 'Crack'
    return predictedLabelString

if __name__ == "__main__":
   predictedLabelString = predict_image_util("<val>")
   print(predictedLabelString)
```

If you still want to use a variable defined on module level and operate that in a method, I suggest using nonlocal(valid only on python3)https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement

Answer (score 1):

when you assign a value in a function python considers it as another local variable.
you do not access it from outside of function and you can not modify it from inside of function.
you need to add a global word before it in function to modify that global variable. 
but if you want the best and cleanest way to do this you can use a class like this:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, predictedLabelString=''):
        self.predictedLabelString = predictedLabelString

    def predict_image_util(self, finalPredictedInv):
        self.predictedLabelString = 'Crack'

    def another_function(self):
        plt.title(self.predictedLabelString)
```

and use it like this:

```
a = MyClass()
a.predict_image_util(finalPredictedInv='something')
a.another_function()
```